# Using addcslashes on string to escape backtick

Tags: php, escaping, backticks

If i have the following string, i try to escape the backticks before passing to node vm.script(`...`) for execution

```
// test has been previously declared
$someStr = "test = `more/${test}`";
$escapedSomeStr = sprintf('%s', addcslashes($someStr, "`"));
```

I end up with double backslashes before the backticks like so if i output $escapedSomeStr i get the following

```
test = \\`more/${test}\\`
```

Some reading i've been doing indicates that PHP used to have magic quotes which adds the extra slash, but it doesnt appear to be turned on.

Comment: I can’t tell, are you trying to use [backticks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) for execution in PHP?

Comment: Not for execution in PHP. the escaped string gets passed to ```sprintf(vm.Script(`%s`), $escapedSomeStr);``` the result of which then gets executed in node via a call through a php process

Comment: How are you outputting the value? Some debug outputs themselves add escaping in some contexts, so might confuse things

Comment: Works for me. https://3v4l.org/1Zovg It's what IMSoP said.